# Re-running workflow state in wf 4.0 state machine

Tags: android-activity, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, state-machine

I have created a State machine workflow in WF 4.0 and it has following steps.

State 1 : RunExe
State 2: LoadData
State 3: VerifyData
state 4: ExportData
State 5: Complete

Each of above state will have a recevie and send activity which contains the code activities to execute in between. Suppose, if i fails to verify data (step 3) i want to re-run Step 2 and do step 3 again.

Can anyone let me know how this can be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a state transition back to state 2 and have that execute on a verification failure.